# Can't get el-checkbox works inside of Element UI slot

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/23efpswu/

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/element-ui/lib/index.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <el-table :data="tableData" style="width: 100%">

        <el-table-column label="id" width="220"> 
           <template slot-scope="scope"> {{ scope.row.id }}</template>
        </el-table-column>

        <el-table-column label="name" width="220"> 
           <template slot-scope="scope"> {{ scope.row.name }}</template>
        </el-table-column>    

     <el-table-column label="status" width="120"> 
             <template slot-scope="scope"><el-checkbox v-model="!scope.row.isEnabled" ></el-checkbox> </template>
    </el-table-column>         

  </el-table>
</div>
```

```
    var Main = {
      data() {
          return {
                tableData: [
                {id: 1, name: "One", isEnabled: false},
                {id: 2, name: "Two", isEnabled: false},
                {id: 3, name: "Three", isEnabled: false},
                {id: 4, name: "Four", isEnabled: true},
              ],

          }
        },
        created() {

        },
        methods: {

       }
    }
    var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
    new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

When I am clicking on checkbox I am getting error: `Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value: false`.

How to get checkbox works inside scope? I seen to update data in model on click to checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According Vue's documentation, `v-model="item.prop"` is just syntactic sugar for:
`v-bind:value="item.prop" v-on:input="item.prop = $event.target.value"`.

So if we use your current implementation, it would look like this:

```
<el-checkbox v-bind:value="!scope.row.isEnabled" v-on:input="!scope.row.isEnabled = $event.target.value"></el-checkbox>
```

If I'm not wrong, assigning it as `!scope.row.isEnabled` would mean you have  an `undefined` property assigned to your `v-model` and that's why this error occurs.

```
Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value: false
```

To solve it, remove the `!` from the `v-model` assignment.

```
<el-checkbox v-model="scope.row.isEnabled" ></el-checkbox>
```

This will assign the new value of the checkbox to `scope.row.isEnabled`.

See [working implementation](https://jsfiddle.net/analizapandac/pzsnmagu/1/)